# what is the meaning of the following function syntax in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I encountered the following function call in a nodejs project.

```
var setEnv = function(envCtor) {
  if (typeof envCtor == 'string') {
    envCtor = ({
      node: ENV_node
    })[envCtor];
  }

  ENV = new envCtor({
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar
  });
  this.__env = ENV;
  this.__dir = ENV.getCwd();
};

function ENV_node() {
  //some code
};

setEnv('node');
```

I don't get the syntax, can anybody help me to understand whats going in this function ?
TIA

Comment: What part of the syntax don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks I would first like to understand  what `envCtor = ({
      node: ENV_node
    })[envCtor];` is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would first like to understand what `envCtor = ({ node: ENV_node })[envCtor];` is doing

Having determined that `envCtor` is a string, it's setting it to either:

- `ENV_node` (if `envCtor` is `"node"`), or
- A standard object property (e.g., any of the ones on `Object.prototype`) if `envCtor` is `"toString"`, `"valueOf"`, etc., or
- `undefined`

*(I couldn't guarantee that they did that second one intentionally, given what they do with `envCtor` later. :-) `toString` isn't a constructor function.)*

The *way* it's doing that is by creating an object with one "own" property, `node`, and then the usual set of inherited properties, then looking up the value of the property whose name matches the `envCtor` string. Here's a version split into its parts:

```
var tempObj = {node: ENV_node};
var newValue = tempObj[envCtor];
envCtor = newValue;
```

The reason for the `()` is to avoid confusion with creating a block rather than an object with `{node: ENV_node}`. However, there's no real need for them and they could be removed. The parser won't treat the `{` as the beginning of a block, as it appears on the right-hand side of an assignment operator.

Example:

```js
var ENV_node = "the ENV_node value";
function test(envCtor) {
    var before = envCtor;
    envCtor = { node: ENV_node }[envCtor];
    console.log(before + " -> " + envCtor);
}
test("node");
test("toString");
test("foo");
```

Comment: "The reason for the () is to avoid confusion" ... It didn't help :) ... Neither did using the square-bracket property reference right after object literal - didn't know that was possible. Or does that require the parentheses? Good explanation!

Comment: @mc01: *""The reason for the () is to avoid confusion" ... It didn't help :) ."* LOL! Yeah. :-)